# undefined reference capturing static variable in lambda

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, lambda

I have a lambda inside of a function that is capturing with `[&]` and then using a local static variable inside the lambda.  I'm not sure if this valid to begin with, but this compiles and links fine:

```
void Foo()
{
    static int i = 5;

    auto bar = [&]()
    {
        i++;
    };

    bar();
}

int main()
{
    Foo();
}
```

But by making `Foo` a templated function:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo()
{
    static int i = 5;

    auto bar = [&]()
    {
        i++;
    };

    bar();
}

int main()
{
    Foo<int>();
}
```

I get the following error:

> g++-4.7 -std=c++11 main.cpp 
>   /tmp/cctjnzIT.o: In function 'void Foo()::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const': 
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to 'i' 
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to 'i' 
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

So, I have two questions:

1. Is using `i` in the first example even valid c++?
2. If #1, then what is wrong with the second example?  Or is this a gcc bug?

Comment: Technically, only variables with automatic storage duration are "captured".  In both examples, the reference to `i` is just an ordinary valid lvalue use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes, you can even drop `&` from definition because `static` is always accessible in lambda function.
2) It is bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54276

Answer (score -2):

1) Yes, assuming you're intending to have 'i''s value persist between calls.

2) It's not a bug in the compiler.  The static instance variable needs to also be defined via a template.  Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553854/template-static-variable).

Comment: That post is about static class members, not statics local to functions.  How do I explicitly refer to those?

Comment: I think you end up with a problem.  Mainly b/c each template specialization is instantiated when you use it (and therefore you get multiple instances of your static variable).