# c++ static class variable without cpp file

Tags: c++, static-members

I have a simple class for storing sensor data which can be summarized as

```
class Data
{
  public:
  Data(){timestamp = Time::now(); id = sNextID++; data = 0; type = DATA_TYPE_UNKNOWN;}

  double data;
  Time timestamp;
  DataType type;

  private:
  static unsigned int sNextID;
};
```

I have a header file that declares a bunch of similar data classes. Given the simplicity of the classes there is no need for an implementation cpp file.

The problem is, without an implementation file how do I initialize sNextID? I read somewhere that it defaults to 0 which would be fine, although relying on that seems a bit hackish. More importantly, though, without initializing it somewhere the linker complains of an undefined reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**inline function**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5057065/1762344) (free-standing or member):

```
inline unsigned &sNextID()
{
    static unsigned data = 0;
    return data;
}
```

Or **class template** (defenition of it's statics [can be in header file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553875/1762344)):

```
template<typename tag>
struct Foo
{
    static unsigned sNextID;
};

template<typename tag>
unsigned Foo<tag>::sNextID=0;
```

Update: In C++17 `inline` variables are available:

```
struct Foo
{
    static inline unsigned sNextID;
};
```

Comment: Oh, I like the template option. I haven't gotten around to using templates yet but I'm going to be moving in that direction anyhow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in the header file (let's say it's name is data.h), add this at the end

```
class Data
{
    .....
  private:
  static unsigned int sNextID;
};

#ifdef MY_INIT
unsigned int sNextID = 0;
#endif
```

in the file where you have main

```
#define MY_INIT
#include "data.h"
```

in all other files where you are including the header, just a plain

```
#include "data.h"
```

This will ensure that the line `unsigned int sNextID = 0;` will be compiled into only one translation unit - the one with `main`.