# Static variable in template class causing C2371 'redefinition; different basic types'

Tags: c++

I have a template class with a static member variable. However, when compiling, I get the following error:

```
C2371: 'S_TYPES' : redefinition; different basic types
```

Here's the class in question:

```
// This all is in Type.h

template<class T>
class Type
{
private:
    static std::map<unsigned int, Type<T>> S_TYPES;
};

template<class T>
std::map<unsigned int, Type<T>> Type<T>::S_TYPES;
```

How do I fix the error here?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Now there is! Made a mistake when copy-pasting.

Comment: Also did you mean `std::map<unsigned int, Type<T>> S_TYPES;`?

Comment: @MattMcNabb he edited the question as soon as he saw the error, I posted the original code

Comment: be aware that you may have link issues [as detailed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553854/template-static-variable) although I'm not sure if C2371 is such an issue

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ not a duplicate of that

Comment: [works fine in VC++ online tester](http://rextester.com/AWQZ70756),  please double-check that if you compile the exact code you post, then you get the error message you claim

Comment: @MattMcNabb Marco A. already posted the correct solution. It was a copy-paste problem.

Comment: OK, so you edited the correct answer into the question during the grace period? right-o :)

Comment: @manabreak You don't need to post to save your question, it's draft backed up automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP edited the question as soon as he saw the error: you were defining a different type from the declared one:

```
template<class T>
class Type
{
private:
    static std::map<unsigned int, Type<T>> S_TYPES;
};

template<class T>
std::map<unsigned int, Type<T>, TypeInfoComparator> Type<T>::S_TYPES; // different
```

you should make sure that they do match:

```
template<class T>
class Type
{
private:
    static std::map<unsigned int, Type<T>> S_TYPES;
};

template<class T>
std::map<unsigned int, Type<T>> Type<T>::S_TYPES;
```

Comment: Yeah. It was actually a copy-paste issue right from the start in my original code.

Comment: No problem, glad we straightened that out