# C++ value definition in cpp file and extra qualification

Tags: c++, matrix, static-members, undefined-reference

I am programming a template matrix with multi-threading.
I need my matrix to be able to work with this code line (which i cannot change, it's a demand from my program):

```
Matrix<Complex>::setParallel(false);
```

so for this parallel (which is a bool decides if to use multi-threading or not) must be static.

So at start i defined it like that:

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
private:
...
public:
static bool parallel;
...
};
```

but then i got this error:

```
... undefined reference to 'Matrix<int>::parallel'
```

after a quick search i got to this question in stack overflow: [Undefined reference to a static member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110487/c-undefined-reference-to-to-static-member)

so i go ahead and to what the answers said.
so i changed my code to:

```
   template<class T>
    class Matrix
    {
    private:
    ...
    public:
    static bool Matrix::paraller;
    ...
    };
```

and now i get this error:

```
extra qualification 'Matrix<T>::' on member 'paraller' [-fpermissive]
```

(note: i also tried static "bool Matrix::paraller;" instead, didn't help.

now i don't know how to get rid of the extra qualification error without getting back the undefined reference again.

if that matters, the whole code is in a file named: "Matrix.hpp", which i cannot change (another demand from my project).

what should i do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) please.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't see anywhere in that thread where it covers the case of static variable in a class template (which is not obvious how to handle)

Comment: and how to i provide an out-of-line definition?

Comment: By looking up "template static member definition" on Google.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a few pages suggest `template<class T> bool Matrix<T>::parallel;` in the header, but none of the answers explain why it's not an ODR violation to then instantiate that in two different units. (There seems to be an explicit provision in [basic.def.odr]/6 that "static data member of a class template" may be instantiated in multiple units so long as the initializer (if any) follows the rules in that clause, but it took me a while to find that)

Comment: @M.M: I don't think the average Joe really cares about _why_ it's valid, as long as it is. Of course, you and I are not those people. :)

Comment: @M.M: please feel encouraged to formulate an encyclopedic answer yourself.

Comment: @decltype_auto i'm not completely sure what the answer is, otherwise I already would have :)

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553854/template-static-variable) has some useful info

Comment: @M.M But then it would be an idea to ask a question yourself, wouldn't it?

Comment: @decltype_auto the same question has been asked a few times already, but nobody's given a clear answer with standard references

Comment: @M.M: Well - judging by your ingenuities, "clear" appears to relative. Whether sth is an answer to the question "what should [the questioner] do?" is not.

Comment: @decltype_auto i'm not sure what point you're trying to make, sorry

Comment: @M.M Try harder to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Proper static class members usage is best described in this code snippet

```
struct A
{
   static bool concurrent;
};

A::concurrent = false;
```

or, if the member is `const`

```
struct B
{
   static const bool concurrent = false;
};
```

Specifying the **template** static class member is exactly the same. And one thing come out: *static member initialization must be available at the scope of declaration*. This means, you *can't* decouple declaration out of implementation - they must be *exactly* in the same program unit. Nevertheless, this is the common requirement for every template unit, whether it is an object, a function, etc.

Thus, creating a non-const template static class member is performed this way

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename... Rest>
struct TemplateStruct
{
   static U variable;
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Rest>
TemplateStruct<T, U, Rest...>::variable = U();
```

Where `U` may be any type you want, while it has a `default constructor`.