# Initialise static data members using lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to concept of using lambda functions in C++. My aim is to initialise a static data member array of objects using lambda function. Below is my code -

```
#include <iostream>
class B
{
    public:
    B() {std::cout << "B Called" <<std::endl;}
    B(int y){std::cout << "B int Called" <<std::endl;}
};
class A
{
    public:
    A(){std::cout << "Called" << std::endl;}
    static B bobj[256];
};

B bobj[256] = [] () {for (int i = 0 ; i < 256; i++) { bobj[i] = new B(2)}};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

But I am getting compilation error **'ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘B’ and ‘B*’)'** and others.

How can I code a lambda function to initialise an array of objects?

Comment: Actually I have a templated class. A class type would be passed for its creation and in it an array of its type needs to be created - the array of objects would be used for a pre designed finite available data.

Comment: Some reason why you can't do it in `A`'s constructor under the control of an `if bobj[0] == nullptr)`?

Comment: The reason is that in this case it is class B but since actually A is a templated class  - it can be of any class type - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778336/initialise-large-static-class-array

Comment: Don't comment on your own question -- edit your question with any additional relevant data you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think see at least *one* of your problems. Your definition of `bobj` is an array of `B` objects:

```
B bobj[256]
```

Yet you are trying to assign a *pointer-to-B* to it (by using `new`):

```
bobj[i] = new B(2)
```

I believe that's the cause of the error you've shown, `ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'B' and 'B*')`. The "others" you mention I can't really comment on, because you haven't shown them to us :-)